# Where are the Parent themes CSS & PHP files hidden on Wordpress?

Tags: wp-admin, css, admin-css

I have a friend who has a wordpress website, he wants some help and as I have been coding with html, css, javascript (but with bootstrap) I am helping him out. However, he has a very old version of the Customizr theme on wordpress and as I haven't used wordpress much I cannot find the full code and CSS for the website. The options on the custom editor are extremely limited and I would really need to see more code for the website, it just seems it is all...hidden?!

He thinks I have full admin access, I am logged in as "admin".. could his old designer (who has gone AWOL) be hiding them to stop him changing them?

When I got to the parent theme, the header is only 10 lines long! None of the code for the navbar etc is in there, and the parent CSS file is empty, the child CSS file just has around 50 lines of custom CSS and that is it.

it says in the parent theme:

/**
* The styleheets of Customizr are located in inc/css. Each skin has its own stylesheet : blue.css, green.css, ...
*

but inc/css are nowhere to be seen!!

Could someone please enlighten me where the CSS and header/footer etc code is hiding? I do have quite a lot of coding experience but I really do not know much about wordpress, so please point me in the right direction of how I can find the main CSS code and the real header file etc instead of telling me not to modify the code etc.

Sorry if I am being ridiculously stupid but a google search has yielded me no information on this which bought me here.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly:

Go to your Wordpress installation public_html folder, open up wp-config.php and past this into it on its own line at the bottom:

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false);
```

that will then activate the "Editor" tab on the flyout menu in the themes "Appearance" link.

Be careful WP has no option (well it may do now but i highly doubt it) to reverse any changes or has syntax highlighting, your best option is to ftp the themes style.css to your workstation, copy it, then work on it remotely and upload when done, the copy is your insurance policy if it all goes wrong you can just reupload the original version.

when done either remove the line you pasted into the config file or change false to true to hide the editor again.

Comment: Hey thanks for this, but where abouts is that? On the server or in wordpress?

Comment: I do not have access to the server as the old designer has all the log-ins and has abandoned his job!

Comment: Oh, and the editor is there in the appearance menu, along with parent and child theme but the parent them files such as header.php are almost empty! I am so confused I think there must be more code than this, ie the code for the actual theme, I cannot find it anywhere!

Comment: The file is in the public html folder. tell your buddy to contact his hosting company and have the logins reset, thats a security issue.

Comment: Sorry i cant help you with that as i never use child themes, something in my psyche just tells me they aint worth the effort, im old school i guess..

Comment: Okay great thanks, will do. I was reading how you can get it back from the hosting company. Nightmare! So for future reference when I get access, the files will just be in there? As it is showing me a header.php and footer.php file in the parent theme in the editor (under appearances) but will there be more files/code here? Just because you said this would activate the editor tab and it is already activated, just seems to be hiding a bit

Comment: probs the old/ex designer activated the editor himself (or its a really old wp install), these days its deactivated out of the box as it was causing lots of issues with folks wrecking their own sites css (especially as there is no going back with the WP editor)

Comment: Ah no worries, I never use them or templates or wordpress, hence my difficulty!

Comment: it is a very very old wordpress install.. years old